# Pass multiple argument from command line

Tags: python, command-line

i trying with

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   dpd = ''
   opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile=","dpd="])

   print(opts)
   
   for opt, arg in opts:
      print(opt)
      if opt == '-h':
         print ('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-d","--dpd"):
         dpd = arg
   print ('Input file is ', inputfile)
   print ('Output file is ', outputfile)
   print ('DPD', dpd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

and run with `python3 demo.py -i 65 -o ale -d 45` but it's give error

getopt.GetoptError: option -d not recognized

and i want to pass 6 pass argument how can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `argparse`, which is simpler and much more powerful than `getopt`.

But the problem is that you forgot to declare `-d` as an option:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:d:",["ifile=","ofile=","dpd="])
```

Comment: how to set type? in this function??

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for this in Python. I strongly recommend that you use it - you get a lot of stuff out of the box and the errors will be more informative.

```py
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-d', '--dpd')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-d', 'bla'])
>>> args.dpd
'bla'
```

If you just add the rest of your arguments your program becomes much simpler:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--ifile')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--ofile')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dpd')

print(f'dpd: {args.dpd}')
print(f'input: {args.ifile}')
print(f'output: {args.ofile}')
```

You get the help arg with autoexit out of the box too.

You can also specify which parameters are required and which are optional, set default values and a lot more.

Comment: how Can i pass Blank value??

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: From the shell, you just need to make sure you have a quoted empty string, something like `-o ''`. By default in `argparse`, the value assigned to an unused option is `None`, but you can change that with the `default` keyword argument to `add_argument`. E.g. `parser.add_argument('-o', '--ofile', default='')`.

Comment: You can also just omit it if it’s an optional arg